# Why do my singular-named routes, with plural equivalents no longer work in Ember.js RC6?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Why do my singular-named routes, with plural equivalents no longer work in Ember.js RC6?

After upgrading from Ember.js RC4 to Ember.js RC6, most of my routes continue to work with a couple of exceptions:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route 'note', {path: 'note/:id'}
  @route 'notes', {path: 'notes'}
  @route 'attendee', {path: 'attendee/:id'}
  @route 'attendees', {path:'attendees'}
```

The note and attendee singular routes, stop functioning. I've attempted to setup a custom controller method using transitionToRoute instead of using the linkTo helper in handlebars, but neither approach works anymore. Rolling back to RC5 or RC4 corrects the issue, so I can only assume this has to do with the router facelift, but I can't seem to find documentation on what I should be doing instead.

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle/jsbin example for yours issue. Does your routes uses any of changed Route hooks (see: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/06/23/ember-1-0-rc6.html) ?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the issue under smaller circumstances, but no luck yet. This is a fiddle of what I had worked previously, but is not longer working, but in a much larger project with many more components and pieces. At the very least if I could get an error that would be great.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rjfranco/GKBbu/2/